# Because every version of alpha_vantage_package depends on http ^0.12.0+4 and front depends on http ^0.13.4, alpha_vantage_package is forbidden

Tags: flutter, dependencies, alpha-vantage

I tried to install `alpha_vantage` and got the following error:

***Because every version of alpha_vantage_package depends on http ^0.12.0+4 and front depends on http ^0.13.4, alpha_vantage_package is forbidden.
So, because front depends on alpha_vantage_package ^1.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because front depends on alpha_vantage_package ^1.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1***

This is my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: front
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0-116.0.dev <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.11
  get: ^4.6.1
  google_fonts: ^2.1.1
  universal_platform: ^1.0.0+1
  alpha_vantage_package: ^1.0.0


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alpha_vantage_package` was created two years ago and had no updates since then, hence its dependencies need to be updated.

I've created [PR](https://github.com/basilzuberi/alpha_vantage_package/pull/1) to the original repository with dependency updates, maybe at some point the author will publish an update for the package.

Meanwhile, you may use the package from my repo. Put this into `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
  alpha_vantage_package:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/olexale/alpha_vantage_package
```

Comment: can we do this with every package which is outdated.
it is not illegal to edit someone's other packages and use them?

Comment: This is legal if package’s license allows this. In fact, that’s how OSS works.

Comment: How will I know that this is legal and the package who made this is allowing it?
and can I use this in the production app? will it be secure and safe?
I am curious because I have one old app with the same problem.

Comment: The majority of packages have a LICENSE file with the license. This particular package has an MIT license (https://github.com/basilzuberi/alpha_vantage_package/blob/master/LICENSE) which encourages collaboration. It's 100% safe to use it in production.

Comment: I think it still has a problem: `Because front depends on flutter_alpha_vantage_package any which requires SDK version >=1.19.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.`

Comment: Do you know how can I fix the new issue or I must forget using this package?

Answer (score 1):

if you get this error which is very common as the packages get updated frequently and not every version matches with other packages.
It means **alpha_vantage_package**  depends on a dependency with a version lower than you specified in another dependency.

To solve this, open **pubspec.yaml**, and remove the version number of the problem dependency:

Example:

Change

`alpha_vantage_package : ^1.0.0` --> remove this number
To:

```
alpha_vantage_package:
```

and I can also see in [pubdev](https://pub.dev/packages/alpha_vantage_package) that alpha_vantage_package is not updated to null safety. Try not to use this package as its latest update was 2 years ago.